# Seg fault using C++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, find, std, unordered-map

I'm sometimes hitting a seg fault in my code using a std::unordered_map. The top of the stack trace looks like this:

```
[  0] 0x00007f879eea2a71 std::_Hashtable, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, reference::property::RefEntityType::Value>, std::allocator, std::allocator > const, reference::property::RefEntityType::Value> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::allocator > >, std::hash, std::allocator > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits >::_M_find_before_node(unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned long) const at ...)
[  1] 0x00007f879eea1e5e std::_Hashtable, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, reference::property::RefEntityType::Value>, std::allocator, std::allocator > const, reference::property::RefEntityType::Value> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::allocator > >, std::hash, std::allocator > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits >::_M_find_node(unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned long) const at ...)
```

Where `reference::property::RefEntityType::Value` is my class. The important part of the stack trace seems to be that it's calling `"_M_find_before_node"` and `"_M_find_node"` which appears to be used in the unordered_map "find" functionality. Here is my code that's accessing the map (the actual map is longer but I shortened it):

```
RefEntityType::Value RefEntityType::stringToEnum(const std::string &enumString) {
  static const std::unordered_map<std::string, Value> enumConversionMap = {{"function", Value::Function},
                                                                           {"class", Value::Class},
                                                                           {"method", Value::Method}};

  const auto enumPos = enumConversionMap.find(enumString);
  if (enumPos == enumConversionMap.cend()) {
    return Value::Unknown;
  }
  return enumPos->second;
}
```

Like I said it only happens sometimes, the code itself is threaded and this code will run at startup of my program as well as different points during it. Does anyone see any obvious problems with this? Is the fact that the map is "static" make a difference?

Comment: The C++ standard guarantees that a static object is fully constructed before use, even under conditions of concurrent access during construction.  Since this is a static const object, I don't see how it's possible for this particular bit of code to crash unless you have heap corruption somewhere.  Perhaps `enumString` itself is part of an object that is destroyed or otherwise corrupt.  Hard to say, since you have chosen to show so little code.

Comment: a static variable in the function is typically initialized when the function is called for the first time. The compiler keeps a hidden flag for it which is not thread safe. So, the best solution is to move this static in global scope.

Comment: @Serge that is only true prior to C++11.  From C++11 onward, function local static initialization is guaranteed thread-safe.

Comment: Weird memory issues when allocating memory are almost always caused (for me) by someone already having done something naughty, and the real problem isn't where you're looking. * pointers are so 2001. Smart pointers...